# Get array values having same key from one array and store those values in another array

Tags: php

I am working on a php project. I am stuck at this point.

Here is the array that I have.

```
[text_numeric] => Array
    (
        [text] => Numeric field fillable by user
        [parameters] => Array
            (
                [prefix] => 1
                [price] => 1
                [sku] => 
                [quantity] => 
                [weight] => 
                [min_value] => 1
                [max_value] => 1
            )

        [operand] => Array
            (
                [op_fix_discount] => 1
                [op_fix_recharge] => 1
                [op_per_unit] => 1
                [op_percentage] => 
            )

    )

[checkbox] => Array
    (
        [text] => Checkbox attributes
        [parameters] => Array
            (
                [prefix] => 1
                [price] => 1
                [sku] => 1
                [quantity] => 1
                [weight] => 1
                [min_value] => 
                [max_value] => 
            )

        [operand] => Array
            (
                [op_fix_discount] => 1
                [op_fix_recharge] => 1
                [op_per_unit] => 
                [op_percentage] => 1
            )

    )
```

I want to get all the values from this array with key value "text" in another array.
Like this:

```
Array
(
    [0]=>Numeric field fillable by user
    [1]=>Checkbox attributes
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could have been great if you had show us your efforts to achieve that but since you are new here is the codez. You can simply get it using a `foreach loop`,

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($your_array as $k=>$row){
   $new_array[$k] = $row['text'];
}
print_r($new_array);
```

You can also use [array_map](https://www.php.net/array_map),

```
function getTextField($a) {
    return $a['text'];
}
$texts = array_map('getTextField', $your_array);
print_r($texts);
```

Comment: oops i am new here. is it ok now?